# include a certain file dependant on a drop down result

Tags: php, html-select

I'm asking here as I'm just not sure what to call what I'm looking for so I cant find a result. I have checked dynamic drop downs but that's basically filling a drop down list with results from a database, what I want to do is when using a drop down and I select for example 'a' from the results, I would like it to 'include' the associated file 'example/a.php' if I select b, 'include example/b.php' and so on. I'm just wondering how can this be done and can anyone point me in the right directions so I can learn to do this?

Answer (score 0):

that is quite easy, simply type

```
require 'examples/'.$_POST['dropdown'].'.php';
```

of course do some checks on the input you get from the user.